# Flex 3: Creating and populating a new XML file on the server to be reloaded at a later date

Tags: xml, apache-flex, export

I have an application that reads in an external XML file, parses out the pieces, displays them, and then allows the user to edit them.  I would like to have a save button that the user can press that would save any changes to a new XML document somewhere on the server (any file location that I specify).  I've been looking around online, and can't find any examples... all I can find is that this ability wasn't available until flash v.10.

Another option i was considering was to create an XML variable, create it's value, and then somehow forward the user to a coldfusion page where I could then create a file.

If anybody can help me out with either of these two methods, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, this ability has been around *forever*.  You're just 'saving' a string to the server.  Nothing complex with that.  You just need to make sure what the server has a service that can save said string to whatever format needed.

I'm not too sure what's the difficulty.  You do have some kind of server right?  Maybe show some code?